# When $x=c^2$, we write $c= \pm \sqrt{x}$. For higher powers, do we still write $\pm$ only?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When we write $x=c^2$ , then we write $c= \pm \sqrt{x}$

What is the case when it is cube root or $4$th power of root ? Do we still write $\pm$ only ?

Comment: Is it your intention that $x$ be a real number? a complex number?

Comment: well, there are $4$ $4$th rooths of unity, $1,-1,i,-i$, so I don't think that plus or minus makes sense

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  x is real number here.

Comment: I have no idea about why to consider i here ? Please help me on that

Answer (score 4):

First of all, one needs to understand that $\pm$ is a *shorthand* in writing. "$c=\pm\sqrt{x}$" means "$c=\sqrt{x}$ or $c=-\sqrt{x}$".

Second, I presume you are working with real numbers. In that case, when $x$ is negative, then $c^2=x$ has no solutions in $c$, and if $x\ge 0$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is well defined, and the solutions for $c$ are precisely $\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Which brings us to the question: (a) Which other equations are you solving, and (b) In which set of numbers.

### Real number case

Start with $c^3=x$. If you are working with real numbers, then this has a unique solution for every $x$, and this solution is given by $c=\sqrt[3]{x}$. No $\pm$. The story is the same for all *odd* exponents ($c^5=x, c^7=x$ etc.)

For *even* exponents, e.g. $c^4=x$, the situation is the same as for the square. If $x\lt 0$ there is no solution. If $x\ge 0$, the solutions are $c=\pm\sqrt[4]{x}$ (and similarly for $c^6=x, c^8=x$ etc.)

### Complex number case

I was about to write a quite long story here, as the situation is, erm, a lot more complex. (Pun intended.) It involves talking about roots of $1$ and about trigonometry (the "polar form" of a complex number).

- If $x\ne 0$ there are always $n$ different solutions in $c$ for $c^n=x$, and if $n=2$, the solutions are still given by $c=\pm\sqrt{x}$.
- However, the symbol $\sqrt{x}$, and even more the symbol $\sqrt[n]{x}$, is *ambiguous*.
- However, there are ways to resolve this ambiguity by *adopting a certain convention*. ("Choosing a branch of a multi-valued complex function" is what this is called.)
- However, in teaching, different people adopt different conventions :( and so the whole thing is a mess.

Let's not get there in this post.

Comment: Let's not even get into what happens in quaternions.

Comment: @J.G. I *was* seriously considering at least mentioning negative and rational (maybe real, or even complex exponents) before going into quaternions, but then ... nah.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^4=c$, then the solutions are $c= \sqrt[4]{x},-\sqrt[4]{x},i\sqrt[4]{x},-i\sqrt[4]{x}$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit and a primitive 4th root of unity. This works if you work over the reals or complex numbers.

Comment: I don’t why do we consider imaginary number here sir.

Answer (score 0):

**Real numbers**

Every positive number $x$ has $2$ square roots, $1$ cube root, $2$ fourth roots, $1$ fifth root, etc. This means that if $x^4=5$, for instance, then $x=\pm \sqrt[4]{5}$. The symbol $\sqrt[4]{}$ denotes the positive fourth root of a number. So, if we were solving $x^4=10$ but we knew $x>0$, then we would write $x=\sqrt[4]{10}$. If $x$ is a negative number, then it has no square roots, $1$ cube root, no fourth roots, $1$ fifth root etc.

**Complex numbers**

Let $w$ denote a non-zero complex number. The equation $z^n=w$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ has exactly $n$ solutions, i.e. every complex number number has $n$ $n$-th roots. This is a direct consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra:
$$
z^n-w=0
$$
is an $n$-th degreee polynomial, meaning that it has $n$ roots.